Next Auth 5 build error The "original" argument must be of type function. Received undefined in NextJS14
I am trying to implement Next Auth 5 into my project. I am following the installation guide from https://authjs.dev/getting-started/installation . However, when I npm run build I get the following errors:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
and
Failed to collect page data for /api/auth/[...nextauth]
I deleted the whole api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts contraption and the build went through fine. I even tried adding trusted host to either, and both, the .env and the authOptions and the build still failed. Below are my auth.ts and route.ts. I have no other files/code for NextAuth5 in my project.
auth.ts
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export const BASE_PATH = 'api/auth';

const authOptions: NextAuthConfig = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials): Promise<User | null> => {
        const userOne = {
          id: '1',
          userName: 'One',
          password: 'pass',
        };
        if (!credentials) {
          return null;
        }
        if (credentials.username !== userOne.userName) {
          return null;
        }
        return userOne;
      },
    }),
  ],
  basePath: BASE_PATH,
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
};

export const {
  auth,
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth(authOptions);

route.ts
export { GET, POST } from '@/auth';

Please note that when writing this, next-auth@5 is still in beta. BR
